# How to make the infobox appear when pushpin is clicked in windows phone7 Bing maps?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on a Bing maps application in WP7 that pulls pin data from a database, displays the pins on a map.But how to  populates the with the data associated with the pin. Please tell me how to show the custom infobox in WP7.any samples please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

See below example hope you got solution.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitPage();
    }

    private void InitPage()
    {
        testMap.Center = new GeoCoordinate(42,42);
        testMap.ZoomLevel = 10;

        MapLayer pushPinLayer = new MapLayer();
        testMap.Children.Add(pushPinLayer);

        Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();

        pushpin.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(pushpin_Tap);

        pushpin.Content = "SAMPLE";
        pushPinLayer.AddChild(pushpin, new GeoCoordinate(42, 42));

    }

    void pushpin_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Clicked here");
    }
```

}[image]